Relative odds between different unrelated events
I would like to know the method by which to calculate the following…
Based on the provided data, what are the odds of each of these events being highest when they next occur a month from now, and what are the odds of there being a tie amongst the highest events’ outcomes:
The world ranking of the winner of the Byron Nelson Golf Tournament on May 5th (past values: 9, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 15, 5, 3, 11, 6, 3, 2, and 2)
The combined runs scored in the Cubs/Reds game on May 5th (past values: 11, 10, 10, 7, 5, 6, 6, 8, 7, 5, 7, 2, 5, 3, and 7)
The combined runs scored in the White Sox/Giants game on May 5th (past values: 10, 6, 13, 5, 8, 3, 7, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, and 4)
The combined runs scored in the Red Sox/Pirates game on May 5th (past values: 5, 4, 13, 2, 15, 6, 6, 10, 13, 4, 4, 3, 6, 2, and 13)
The most goals scored in the highest scoring of the 10 Premier League soccer games on the weekend of May 4th and 5th (past values: 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 6, 4, and 6)
I’d love to learn the formulas you use to create the odds, including the odds of there being a tie between one or more of the outcomes.
